# mongodb aggregation: Chaining aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Not sure if this can be done, but I gotta ask:

Can I send in multiple aggregation in one request?  In other words, rather than doing the following:

```
one_results = db.results.aggregate([ 
    { $project: { _id: 0, key: "$Field1" }}, 
    { $group: { '_id': '$key', count: { $sum: 1 }}} ])

two_results = db.results.aggregate([ 
    { $project: { _id: 0, key: "$Field2" }}, 
    { $group: { '_id': '$key', count: { $sum: 1 }}} ])
```

I want to do something like this:

```
[one_results, two_results] = db.results.aggregate(
  [ 
    { $project: { _id: 0, key: "$Field1" }}, 
    { $group: { '_id': '$key', count: { $sum: 1 }}} 
  ],
  [ 
    { $project: { _id: 0, key: "$Field1" }}, 
    { $group: { '_id': '$key', count: { $sum: 1 }}} 
  ])
```

I know it's a stretch, but I gotta ask...

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's do-able.  MongoDB doesn't support such a syntax, as yet.  But I'll let the experts weigh in.

Comment: Perhaps you would get a better answer if you showed us the data that you **believe** you need two queries for. I've already proven some peoples **two** query theories incorrect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22314547/2313887

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical answer is definitely no. It's not supported.

The overhead of making the request to the server pales in comparison to the effort of calculating the aggregation results, so there is little benefit in sending two requests as an array. With many drivers, you could just send two separate requests, even asynchronously giving you similar if not better results (if the load could be distributed).

While you could do multiple calculations in one pipeline, you would want to avoid potentially unrelated aggregation calculations, possibly at greater CPU and IO cost than it's worth, and further, many pipelines wouldn't align well enough to combine them into one.

For example, the first pipeline operator were `$match` statements that selected a very different subset of documents, it wouldn't be practical to merge them (it's often recommended to try to filter as many documents using an index as the first step of a pipeline).

Comment: Darn.  I was hoping there was some magic I could do!  Oh well!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible using `$facet`, see [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

In your use case:

```js
results = db.results.aggregate([ 
{ $facet:
   {
      one_result: [ 
          { $project: { _id: 0, key: "$Field1" }}, 
          { $group: { '_id': '$key', count: { $sum: 1 }}} ],
      two_result: [ 
          { $project: { _id: 0, key: "$Field2" }}, 
          { $group: { '_id': '$key', count: { $sum: 1 }}}  ],
   }
}];

// result 1
... = results[0].one_result

// result 2
... = results[0].two_result
```